# Shared Memory segment multiple strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, shared-memory

Hello I have a shared memory segment and I want to put multiple strings in the shared memory I have tried using malloc but failed and also tried to make double pointer which also didnt work.

My question is how do I send multiple strings through `shmat`. the code below is what  I used just to send a single string but I would like to send multiple strings.

```
char *temp;
char *shm;
shmid = shmget(key, size, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
temp=shm;
```

Comment: Use `memcpy()` to copy the strings into the shared memory.

Comment: You'll have to do your own memory management, there's nothing buillt in that keeps track of everything.

Comment: but can you have multiple `shmat` under each process?

Comment: Yes, you can. But using a separate shared memory segment for each string would be very inefficient.